# Windows Form User Control is not displaying at client pc in web page after deploy of website on server

Tags: html

I have a Windows Form User Control containing a button, I added it to my website using:

```
<object id="UserControl"  classid="http:TestControlLibrary.dll#TestControlLibrary.UserControl1" height="100" width="100"></object>
```

When i run my website in development environment using localhost, every thing is working fine.

when i publish my website on server and access it using `http://<ipaddress:port>/page.aspx` on server itself it is working fine.

but, when i access my web site from client pc it is not showing button in web page.
How to show this button in web page on client pc.

Found the solution,
My site should be included in the trusted sites list of the browser.